# Confusions about weak delegate in swift

Tags: swift, delegates, retain-cycle, weak

Let us suppose we have a protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    fun someFunc()
}

class AClass {
    var delegate: MyProtocol?
}
```

AClass doesn't care if the delegate is a class or struct. What I want is sometimes the delegate can be a class and sometimes it can be assigned to a struct.

My question is if I should make the delegate to be "weak".

If so, I have to make MyProtocol be a "class Protocol" so that the delegate has to be a class only.
If not, when I assign the delegate to class, how can I avoid retain cycle?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should make the delegate to be "weak"

The answer is that if `MyProtocol` is not restricted to classes, you cannot make it weak, the compiler won't let you.

The reason for the above is that `struct`s are value types. There isn't a reference that can be strong or weak, because logically the entire struct is copied in when you assign the delegate.

> how can I avoid retain cycle?

This means that you have got to be careful that your delegate contains no strong references back to the instance of the class. So, for instance

```
struct ConcreteDelegate: MyProtocol
{
    fun someFunc() {}
    var instance: AClass

    init()
    {
        instance = AClass()
        instance.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Causes a reference cycle. It can be broken by declaring `instance` as

```
    weak var instance: AClass!
```

Alternatively, and a better solution (IMO), your protocol functions can pass the instance as a parameter so the delegate never needs to store a reference to the instance.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func someFunc(caller: AClass)
}
```

You'll see the above approach adopted in Cocoa in lots of places, for example with the table view data source protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

I think that you forgot that `struct` are not **reference type but a value type**. Meaning that a class has a reference in the memory heap but **structures, enums haven't**. By remembering this fact, there is no meaning to put `weak` if the delegate of your protocol is a `struct` because **it can't cause a retain cycle.**

You need to worry about retain cycles when you use only **classes**. If your delegate of your protocol is a class put `weak` if you think that your class have a reference of your protocol AND your protocol can have a reference of your class put `weak` that's the retain cycle.

If you want to check it put `deinit` functions when you are testing and see if your class is correctly deinit and not kept in memory.
It's basically what I know hope it will help you.